# Problem rooting kindle with 6.3.1

Tags: rooting, amazon-kindle-fire

I'm rooting a kindle fire for a friend, I installed the driver through the SDK manager and ran KFU, but now that KFU has rebooted the kindle, it is stuck at the bootscreen. Any help?

Comment: Sounds like you might simply be stuck in the wrong bootmode. Have you tried Kindle Fire Unbrick Utility? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1428428